# How can I typehint an instance of an abstract class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, instance, abstract-class

I have a utility method that accepts a function, which I know will be a normal (i.e. not a static) class method.

I want to allow chaining off of the utility method by returning the result of the cached function, which is either null or an instance of the abstract class.

Given the following abstract class, utility method, and calls:

```
abstract class BasePage {
  abstract get baseSelector(): string;
  open() { // app logic... }
}

class DerivedClassOne extends BasePage {
  methodOne() {
    console.log("one");
  }
}

class DerivedClassTwo extends BasePage {
  methodTwo() {
    console.log("two");
  }
}

// here I am telling TS that the inner method returns unknown
const helper = (instanceMethod: () => BasePage): () => unknown) => {
  // but what I want to do is tell TypeScript that we are returning...
  return function() {
    return // the **type of class of the instanceMethod**
  }
};
```

I want to tell the TypeScript compiler that the type being returned is a specific type of derived class, not the abstract parent class, and have VSCode show the correct hint.

That means given the following code:

```
const one = new DerivedClassOne();
const two = new DerivedClassTwo();

const helpOne = helper(one.methodOne);
const helpTwo = helper(two.methodTwo);
```

When hovering the mouse over helpOne, I would want to see a hint for DerivedClassOne. When hovering the mouse over helpTwo, I would want to see a hint for DerivedClassTwo.

Outside of defining a heap of overloads and different function signatures that each accept a different derived class, is it possible to have VSCode show/hint the correct return type for `helpOne` and `helpTwo` based on the class type of the passed in instance method?

Note: edited question to address comments (cheers), removed images

Comment: Could you make this a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue in a standalone IDE?  Right now [there are errors unrelated to your question](https://tsplay.dev/W4n5aN) and the code that shows the problem seems only to be present as an image.

Comment: `fn.bind(fn)` doesn't make sense

Comment: If the passed `fn` returns `null | BasePage`, how come the resulting function always returns `BasePage`?

Comment: Please [do not post paintings of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572), and what is `addItem` even? How does it relate to `once`?

Comment: I *guess* you are looking for generics.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like we just need `T extends BasePage` like shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzPY1N) but there are quite a few hoops we need to jump through to convert from the code in the question to that, and I'm not inclined to write my own subclass of `BasePage` just to test it.  Oh well.

Comment: Oh wow generics totally solved it - it's basically the same as C# (still learning TS, only a month in, haven't quite had time to entirely RTFM) -- thanks for all your feedback, if @Bergi or someone else wants the credit feel free to answer otherwise I will do the Q&A thing in a bit